# Dynamically limit the amount of checkboxes that can be checked by user

Tags: php, jquery

I've created a test and answer system. Each question can either have one or multiple answers, e.g "Please mark 1 answer", "Please mark 3 answers" etc.

Is it possible to limit the amount of checkboxes that the user can check based on this? If the question requires 1 answer, then they can only check 1 of the checkboxes.

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="answer<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>" />
   <?php echo $row['answer']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

It loops through this and pulls in each answer, the amount of answers needed for each questions is dynamic and is controlled by this field (where it can be 1, 2, 3 etc):

```
<?php echo $repeater_row['required_answers']; ?>
```

---

Using the jquery below, although this isn't dynamic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length >= 3) {
        $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", 3);
    }
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var bol = $("input:checkbox:checked").length >= 3;
        $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
    });
});
```

**How can I do it dynamically? Each question has it's answers named in sets, so the first question has an answer set called with their inputs named `name="answer1[]"` the second question has an answer set `name="answer2[]"` and so on.**

Comment: Why not use a radio button, instead?

Comment: @SableFoste The user can click one or multiple answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wrap each set of answers in a div with a max-answers attribute and use that attribute value in your javascript.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pVA3d/4/

My HTML

```
<div class="question" data-max-answers="2">
    Here's a question with up to two answers: <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="A"> A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="B"> B <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="C"> C <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="D"> D <br>
</div>
<div class="question" data-max-answers="4">
    Here's a question with up to 4! <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="A"> A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="B"> B <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="C"> C <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="D"> D <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="E"> E <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="F"> F <br>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question").length > 0) {
            toggleInputs($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question")[0]);        
        }
    });
});

function toggleInputs(questionElement) {
    if ($(questionElement).data('max-answers') == undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        maxAnswers = parseInt($(questionElement).data('max-answers'), 10); 
        if ($(questionElement).find(":checked").length >= maxAnswers) {
            $(questionElement).find(":not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(questionElement).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name` property with `checked` to get the count of checkboxes that are checked:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="some_name"]').click(function () {
    // get count of checked with the same name
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var countLength = $(':checkbox[name="' + name + '"]:checked') 

    if(countLength > 3){
       // too many checked
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code on line 4 has an incorrect closing double-quote at the end. You started the code using outer single-quotes and should close with a single-quote or the code will generate a syntax error. `$(':checkbox[name="' + name + '"]:checked")` should read `$(':checkbox[name="' + name + '"]:checked')` instead. Note the single-quote at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a hidden field in your form, such as `boxnum`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" 
        id="answer<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" 
        value="<?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="boxnum" 
       id="q1boxnum" value="<?php echo $repeater_row['required_answers']; ?>" />
```

Then, with jQuery,

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function(){
  var numboxesallowed =$(#q1boxnum).val();

  $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('checked', true)){
          numboxesallowed = numboxesallowed -1;
  }
  if(numboxesallowed < 0) {
   alert('you checked too many boxes!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var limit = 5; // define the limit.
    $('#divID').on('change', '.select_max', function(){ // div in which you will be displaying your data.
      if($('.select_max:checked').length >= limit){ // condition to check the limit you specified
      alert('Limit to select your list has exceeded.');
      this.checked = false; // return false if limit exceeded. 
      }
  });
});
```